# $z_n=\operatorname{Arg} \left(1+\frac{\alpha}{n}\right), \alpha \text{ fixed},$ converges or diverges.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Question: Find out if the sequence $$z_n=\operatorname{Arg}\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{n}\right), \alpha \text{ fixed},$$ converges or diverges. If it converges find out its limit.

My approach: Let $(s_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence defined by $$s_n=1+\frac{\alpha}{n}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$ Clearly $(s_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is convergent and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=1.$$ Let also $(r_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence such that $$r_n=\left|1+\frac{\alpha}{n}\right|, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

Therefore, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $$s_n=r_n(\cos z_n+i\sin z_n).$$

Thus, $x_n:=\Re(s_n)=r_n\cos z_n$ and $y_n:=\Im(s_n)=r_n\sin z_n$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now since $(s_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is convergent, implies that $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$ and $(y_n)_{n\ge 1}$ are also convergent and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1 \text{ and }\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=0.$$

Again since $(s_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is convergent, implies that $(r_n)_{n\ge 1}=(|s_n|)_{n\ge 1}$ is convergent and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n=\left|\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n\right|=|1|=1.$$

This in turn implies that $(\cos z_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is convergent and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos z_n=1.$$

Now $-\pi\le z_n<\pi$, and $z_{n+1}<z_n, \forall n\in\mathbb{N},$ which implies that $(z_n)_{n\ge1}$ is bounded and monotonically decreasing, hence convergent.

Therefore let $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n=L$. Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos z_n=\cos \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n\right)=\cos L.$$ But, we have shown that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos z_n=1,$ which implies that $\cos L=1$ and hence $L=0$.

Therefore, we can conclude that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n=0.$$

Is this approach correct? Also, what are the other ways to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1 \text{ and }\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=0.$$

Hence you used $z_n \to 0$ to show $z_n \to$ !!

My way:

Let $f(z):=Arg(z)$ for $ z \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}.$ Now let $z_0 \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}.$ It is well known that

$f$ is continuous in $z_0 \iff z_0 \notin \{t \in \mathbb R: t \le 0\}.$

Hence $f$ is continuous at $z_0=1.$ Hence

$$z_n \to f(1)=Arg(1)=0$$

as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: Can you please explain me what you wrote in the first line? I meant that since $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n=1+0.i$, implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=0$. I never used the limit of $(z_n)_{n\ge1}$ to determine those limits here.